# Phonegap issue with Ajax Request

Tags: json, cordova, jsonp, phonegap-build

I have a web application developed in PHP that returns data in JSON format.

I created a HTML to read this data shows them on the Android screen.

Works on the web, via Phonegap Desktop works by connecting smartphone.

But when I generate the APK via build.phonegap.com, it does not.

My JS code:

```
$.support.cors = true;
$(document).ready(function(){           
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://zieltecnologia.com.br/mobile/js_bolsa.php',
        type: 'GET',
        crossDomain: true,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data); 
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('error'); 
        }
    });
});
```

My PHP code:

```
echo json_encode($sXml->Papel[1]['Codigo']);
```

My CONFIG the phonegap:

```
<plugin name="com.indigoway.cordova.whitelist.whitelistplugin" spec="1.1.1" source="pgb" />

<allow-navigation href="*" />
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
```

I've tried using JSONP worked but not connecting locally by Phonegap Desktop.

Grateful!

Comment: Have you added a Content Security Policy meta tag in your HTML?

Comment: don't use the idigoway plugin, use the official one from NPM  and read the doc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@leonardogeranio,
This is a common mistake.

First, you can NOT use files created with *Phonegap Desktop App* and use those files on *Phonegap Build*. You can use those files with *Phonegap CLI*, but not *Build*. It works differently. You need to start with your own boilerplate, or a known working boilerplate.

Here is one to get you started [Phonegap--Generic-Boilerplate7](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/Phonegap--Generic-Boilerplate7)

The following blog post will work for development and make you familiar with what you need, but do not use it for production. 
[An HTML Boilerplate for Phonegap](http://codesnippets.altervista.org/blog/2015/BLOG.2015-06-10.jssnippets.html)
*Use the both as a reference.*

If you are looking for more good examples. Here is another blog post:
 [Hybrid HTML5 Boilerplates: Breaking the Chains of Legacy](http://codesnippets.altervista.org/blog/2015/BLOG.2015-06-20.jssnippets.html)

If you'd like an explanation, on the issues with using *Phonegap Desktop App*, I can write a blog post on this.In the meantime, use another boilerplate.

Finally, if you javascript code sits in the `index.html`, you will need to use the `CSP` along with the [`cordova-plugin-whitelist` plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-whitelist). DO NOT USE THE PLUGIN YOU HAVE LISTED ON THIS PAGE.

Best of Luck.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.

Im new in phonegap.

Today i do the build with CLI

Here is the result:

"BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 4 mins 23.164 secs
Built the following apk(s):
    C:\Users\leonardo.geranio\Desktop\bolsa_mobile\platforms\android\build\outpu
ts\apk\android-debug.apk"

But, in android, still the same error.

Comment: You are a GENIOUS! Works at first time Phonegap Build + Boilerplate!

Save my life!!!!!!