# Embed website in mobile Cordova PhoneGap app; issues on android build

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, jquery-mobile, phonegap-build

I created a very basic PhoneGap application, based on the instructions under "Getting Started" here http://docs.phonegap.com/getting-started/1-install-phonegap/desktop/

At the end of step 4 it explains how to make modifications:

http://docs.phonegap.com/getting-started/4-run-your-app/desktop/

Then I went a bit further and just replaced the `<div class="app"...` part with an iFrame like this:

```
<iframe src="http://www.testing.com" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; border: none;">You need a Frames Capable browser to view this content.</iframe>
```

When I test it via the PhoneGap developer app on my phone it looks good.

Then I created a zip out of the project folder (the folder inside my phonegap workspace that has this project's name), and uploaded it to my account at build.phonegap.com

Then when I download the android apk and install and run on an android the screen looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/at5tC.jpg

So instead of that I've now replaced the iFrame with a javascript like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location="http://www.testing.com";
</script>
```

I've also tried variations where I load the page "onload" or "ondeviceready".

With all my attempts it's the same: It works fine in the PhoneGap developer app on my iPhone, but when I try the same on android it just sits on the page and does nothing, and no error shows up in the phonegap console, other than

[code]listening on 192.168.2.83:3000
200 /**api**/appzip[/code]

I also noticed that my phonegap app builder inserted the following line in the default index.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

... but no such file was created. Not sure if that has anything to do with it?

Comment: If you want to use external content or external files in your app, you have to whitelisten the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay,
you need to start over.

1) you can NOT use the framework from *Phonegap Desktop App* for *Phonegap Build* See recent answer here: [Phonegap issue with Ajax Request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34278926/3255670)

2) you can NOT use a Mobile App as a website wrapper, and submit it to Google Play or Apple iTunes See near the bottom of [#5](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#005) from [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md). It is against Apple policy. Read.

3) you should be loading all your assets locally (javascript, css, fonts, etc). That means the files should be on the device, NOT on the internet. There are very few exceptions. This is "best practice" for mobile apps.

4) You can call `onDeviceReady` from `onLoad`, but it does not matter. `deviceready` waits for `onload` See [#4](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#004) of [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md)

5) As @joerg is suggesting, you need to learn about `whitelists`. This *whitelist* worksheet should help. [HOW TO apply the Cordova/Phonegap the whitelist system](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/the-whitelist-system.md)

6) The line in your index.html, `<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>` should already be there. *Phonegap Build* will add the file. You need to make sure already have that that line is in your `index.html`. If that line is not there, your code will NOT work.

**NOTE to 6)** (Added 2015-12-22)  When you are using *Phonegap Build*, according to the [*current* documentation](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/introduction_getting_started.md.html#what_do_i_upload), it does not matter if you use *cordova.js* or *phonegap.js*. Scroll down to *"Making Sure You can Still Access the PhoneGap API"*

Welcome to Cordova/Phonegap. Best of Luck

Comment: Thanks! I will go through all those things. The URL should be white listed already as I added that to the config (<access origin="http://www.testing.com" browserOnly="true" subdomains="true" />
  <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="true" />), but will go through the entire list you supplied more thoroughly!

Comment: @user3682065, you need to reread the documentation for the [*whitelist*](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-whitelist) plugin. `browserOnly="true"` is no longer valid. I am not sure if *"stay-in-webview"* is still supported.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks! Give me a little bit of time to work through all this.

Comment: So regarding your point #6: I've downloaded your boilerplate from https://github.com/jessemonroy650/Phonegap--Generic-Boilerplate7 - in there you put a "phonegap.js" instead of a "cordova.js". Do I still need to add the latter or does the former alone suffice?

Comment: Good Question, I'll make sure to put a comment in there how. When you are using *Phonegap Build*, according to the [\*current\* documentation](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/introduction_getting_started.md.html#what_do_i_upload), it does not matter if you use *cordova.js* or *phonegap.js*. Scroll down to *"Making Sure You can Still Access the PhoneGap API"*

Comment: Gotcha, perfect, this was the help I needed. Why did google not take me straight to your description and template? :)

Comment: One more question: Can you recommend a good beginner tutorial I can go through with the source you have supplied? I'd like to be able to do more than just embed in an iFrame or redirect to a different location altogether based on what you've said in #2

Comment: Yep. Here are a few links [my notes on phongap](http://codesnippets.altervista.org/phonegap.html); see [Phonegap Demo Apps](http://codesnippets.altervista.org/examples/phonegap/) and [Top Bloggers for Cordova/Phonegap](http://codesnippets.altervista.org/documentation/phonegap/bookmarks/topBloggers.html); Steve Husting seems to have the best stuff. There is some [more stuff on this Blog](http://codesnippets.altervista.org/blog/) Best of Luck.